# laravel5.1 retrieve nested relation using eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1, belongs-to

My table design is:

users: |id|username|...

tickets: |id|supp_id|...

ticket_replies: |id|ticket_id|user_id

My controllers look like:

user:

```
public function tickets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ticket');
}
```

ticket:

```
public function ticket_replie()

    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ticket_replie');
    }

public function supp_id()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id','supp_id');
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
$tickets =  Auth::user()->tickets()->orderBy('status', 'desc')->paginate(2);

return view('protected.ticketsList', [ 
    'tickets' => $tickets,
    ]);
```

In my view I use:

```
 @foreach ($tickets as $ticket)

    <br>
    <br>
    ID: {{$ticket->id}}
    title: {{ $ticket->title}}<br>
    status: {{ returnStatus($ticket->status) }}<br>

     @if($ticket->supporter = null)
        supporter: -<br>
     @else
        supporter: {{ $ticket->supp_id()->username }}
     @endif

    created: {{ $ticket->created_at }}<br>
@endforeach
```

Any idea where I do wrong? I get all the time this error:

Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\resources\views\protected\ticketsList.blade.php)

In my point of view the relation between the tables itself is done correctly.

Comment: Which line foes this Notice relate to?

Comment: One of your tickets does not have supp_id set

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following line :

```
supporter: {{ $ticket->supp_id->username }}
```

You're trying to get property `username` from attribute (non-object) `supp_id`, try to use parentheses `()` to refer to the method `supp_id()` and not attribute  `supp_id` :

```
supporter: {{ $ticket->supp_id()->username }}
```

**Note :** You should put the `foreach` loop inside `@else` clause.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed first post, after editing code to your example error message changed a bit too (see above). I have no idea why, each ticket contains a valid "supp_id" which points to a user account.

Comment: Try to replace `$this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'supp_id');` by `$this->belongsTo('App\User', 'supp_id');`.

Comment: Try in your thinker console `App\Ticket::find(id_of_existing_ticket)->supp_id()`.

Comment: Try also `$ticket->supp_id()->first()->username`.

Comment: `$ticket->supp_id()->first()->username` works, but why "first"? Why does it returns more than one item? Is there a better solution to get this done? Maybe without need of `->first()`? One ticket can only have one supporter.

Comment: This answer is wrong. When you say `$ticket->supp_id()` you reference the relation itself (returned by the relation function). $ticket->supp_id will return related model(s), so this was correct

Comment: I've changed relation to a one to one relation. Check first post.

Comment: @Okneloper and how you will get the attribute `supp_id` from ticket?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Eloquent model has magic __get method set up for this. If you have a public property $supp_id set up on the Ticket class, doing `$ticket->supp_id` will get you the value of that property and you will not be able to retrieve the related models. Or rather you will have to retrieve them using $ticket->getRelationValue('supp_id').

Answer (score 0):

For starters I think your view should be like this so you only loop through the tickets if there are some.

```
@if(!$tickets->count() > 0)
    no tickets created
@else
    @foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
        {{dd($ticket->ticket_replie)}}
        title: {{ $ticket->title}}<br>
        status: {{ returnStatus($ticket->status) }}<br>
        supporter: {{ $ticket->supp_id->username }}
        created: {{ $ticket->created_at }}<br>
    @endforeach
@endif
```